# Join with Group By NOT working

Tags: sql, database, join

I'm joining two tables and based on that loading table by Grouping on Customer_number

```
FROM web.helios_customer_profile cp 
  JOIN web.helios_order_line ol ON (cp.customer_number = ol.customer_number)
  INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE cdm.sa_cdm_customer_sales PARTITION (load_date) 
SELECT cp.customer_number, cp.company_name, cp.qualify_score, cp.contract_type, cp.account_status, cp.is_active, cp.sic_code, 
       cp.email_id, cp.company_size, cp.division_code, cp.company_city, cp.company_state, cp.company_zip, cp.user_id, ol.order_number, 
       ol.item_number, ol.order_date, 
       sum(ol.order_quantity) as total_order_quantity, 
       sum(ol.total_cost_price), 
       sum(ol.total_sale_price), 
       (ol.total_sale_price - ol.total_cost_price) as total_profit 
where ol.order_date between '2015-09-27' and '2015-10-27' 
GROUP BY cp.customer_number;
```

But getting an error

> "FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 1:30 Invalid column
>   reference 'company_name'"

Comment: Tag your question with the database or software that you are using.

Comment: `JOIN ... INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ... SELECT`? What is that doing?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not the first column in the statement, I would double check the spelling / actual name of the column `'cp.company_name'`